# Custom CAF Receiver and built-in slideshow issues

Tags: google-cast, custom-receiver

We are currently working on a Custom CAF Receiver App. We would like to promote some of our contents using the built-in slideshow feature (see : https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features#slideshow). However, when the Receiver is launched, only the splash screen is displayed and not the slideshow. The slideshow only works when going back to idle state after having launched at least one video.
Is there a way to have the slideshow displayed right after the receiver launch? If yes how?

Also, we noticed that the --playback-logo-image (see : https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features#styling-the-player) is always hidden? Is this supposed to be displayed on a TV or is this a dedicated asset for touchscreen enabled Chromecast receiver?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

We are having a similar type issue.  We do not see the slideshow until the user is in the idle state.  We also see either the background-image or splash-image for 10 seconds or so prior to the slideshow starting.  Here is what I have in a sample application.

```
<style>
body {
  /*--background-image: url('./images/bg_loading.jpg');*/
  --slideshow-interval: 5s;
  --slideshow-duration: 1s;
  --slideshow-image-1: url('./images/bg_idle_1.jpg');
  --slideshow-image-2: url('./images/bg_idle_2.jpg');
  --slideshow-image-3: url('./images/bg_idle_3.jpg');
  --logo-image: url('./images/bg_loading.jpg');
  --playback-logo-image: url('./images/icon_logo_small.svg');
  --splash-image: url('./images/bg_loading.jpg');
}
#video-holder {
  --theme-hue: 100;
  --progress-color: #FFFFFF;
  --pause-image: url('./images/icon_pause.svg');
  --spinner-image: url('./images/icon_loading.svg');
}
```

I also cannot get the logo images to appear anywhere.  The documentation is very unclear when it comes to what elements you should associate the CSS styles with.